# Is the name of the community correct?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

The title of this question really sounds very silly, but lets see all of those questions:

- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22665/how-many-valid-routes
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22653/operations-on-stacks-of-coins
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22427/convert-simple-array-to-associative-array-in-php
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22288/shortest-path-with-fuel-constraints
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22287/algorithm-can-you-help-me-solve-it
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21775/how-does-this-obfuscated-javascript-code-work (deleted)
- EDIT: +1 https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22835/infinite-or-finite-loop

Those questions are all off-topic. What they do have in common? Newcomers and outsiders do not understand that this is a programming contest community. The "Programming puzzles" in the name is between no help to misleading for them, so people misunderstands the purpose of this site and posts those off-topic questions here. Or worse, migrate questions from somewhere else to this site.

So, since this is recurring, I started to question the community name. Shouldn't it really be "*Programming Contests & Code Golf*" or "*Programming Tournaments & Code Golf*" instead of "*Programming Puzzles & Code Golf*"?

Should we keep the "*& Code Golf*" in the name or not? A code-golf is a particular type of programming puzzle/contest/tournament, so it is redundant, but we might keep it anyway.

So I added 5 pre-made answers. 3 of those answers are about the first part of the name, I.E. "*Programming Contests*" vs "*Programming Puzzles*" vs "*Programming Tournaments*". The other 2 answers are about keeping vs dropping the "*& Code Golf*". Upvote the ones that you do agree and downvote the ones that you do disagree.

If you have any other suggestions different from the ones that I pre-made, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: I'd suggest that the problem is not the name of the community, but rather with people posting questions without taking a look around and reading the FAQ. If a person just rocks up and posts a question without hanging around for a while and seeing what kinds of questions are asked and what kind of conventions we have here then they can hardly be surprised if they break those conventions or post off topic questions.

Comment: @Gareth Yes, but what I am seeing is that people see the title "Programming Puzzles" and just because they have something that is arguably a puzzle involving programming, they post it here in hope to get help with that (or worse migrate from somewhere else to here). I.E. The title is misleading and induces them into error.

Comment: Why are we fighting over `Code Golf & Programming Contests` and `Programming Contests & Code Golf`

Answer (score 30):

<sup>*Upvote this if you agree and downvote if you disagree.*</sup>

Yes, we should rename this site to *Programming **Contests** & Code Golf*. Or maybe just *Programming Contests*.

<sup>See other answers for about dropping the "*& Code Golf*" or not.</sup>

Comment: But code golf *is* a programming contest. So why not just "Programming Contests"?

Comment: @Doorknob. Ok, I created other 2 answers to decide if we should keep or drop the "*& Code Golf*".

Comment: May be just my weak English skill, but to me both “contest” and “tournament” means a more complex thing, possibly composed by a series of puzzles, with cumulative scoring. So from my point of view “puzzle” is the right word. (I wrote about [my opinion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/676/can-and-should-we-include-the-competitive-programming#comment2536_676) earlier in another question.)

Comment: @Doorknob, perhaps the solution is "Code Golf & Programming Contests" with creative ambiguity in the parsing.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think that makes the most sense, especially because it puts the site's subdomain at the fore.

Comment: I added an answer for Peter's variation, so we can see how sentiment divides between that configuration and this one.

Answer (score 23):

<sup>*Upvote this if you agree and downvote if you disagree.*</sup>

Regardless of the fact that it is "*Programming Puzzles*", "*Programming Tournaments*" or "*Programming Contests*", or something else, we must **keep the "*& Code Golf*"** in the name, even if we all do know that code-golf is a type of programming puzzle/contest/tournament.

<sup>See other answers for about the actual name, regardless of the fact of dropping or not the "*& Code Golf*".</sup>

Comment: I feel it's important that we explicitly state "code golf" in the name of the community. As much as I love popularity contests and the like, I found this site while looking for somewhere to code golf and I don't think I'm alone in that. To an outsider, "Programming Puzzles/Contests/Tournaments" can mean a lot of different things, but if the next words in the title are "Code Golf" it makes them think "oh, things like code golf". Sure, they could look around and see what "programming contests" are, but in my opinion it's important that they immediately have an approximate understanding.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Upvote this if you agree and downvote if you disagree.</sub>

Yes, we should rename this site to **Code Golf & Programming Contests**.

<sub>See other answers for about dropping the "& Code Golf" or not.</sub>

<sub>See other answers for about the actual name, regardless of the fact of dropping or not the "& Code Golf".</sub>

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Upvote this if you agree and downvote if you disagree.*</sup>

Regardless of the fact that it is "*Programming Puzzles*", "*Programming Tournaments*" or "*Programming Contests*", or something else, lets **drop the "*& Code Golf*"** from the name, since code-golf is a type of programming puzzle/contest/tournament, so it is redundant.

<sup>See other answers for about the actual name, regardless of the fact of dropping or not the "*& Code Golf*".</sup>

Comment: +1 *I don't golf*, and every time I visited the site (until *very* recently) the only thing I saw on the front page was golf. This caused me to just plain ignore the site for a long time, and I think many users here see golf as somehow a "better fit" for the site than other challenges/puzzles.

Comment: I don't think it will help the community to drop Code Golf from the name, especially when the site URL is codegolf.SE and the site community originally coalesced around code-golf threads on SO. *But*, I do think we need to be mindful of the fact that not everyone in the community is a golfer. So I'm not up voting this answer but I'm up voting you because your sentiments are valid.

Comment: Relevant comments: [... this is not code golf ... Welcome to Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22720/most-creative-way-to-reverse-a-positive-integer#comment46997_22828)

Comment: @Geobits I'm in two minds about this one. I find golf stupidly boring when the language isn't specified, so I would be more interested in the site if it didn't emphasize golf so much (especially when it's “oh I need a winning criterion so hey let's make it golf”). On the other hand, the current name is a sign that this site just isn't for me. On the gripping hand, I could enjoy code golf if each thread was restricted to a specific language — so maybe this site should drop the “code golf” monicker and let it be used by a site that does it properly.

Answer (score -4):

<sup>*Upvote this if you agree and downvote if you disagree.*</sup>

No, the name of the site is correct and should not be changed. Keep it as *Programming **Puzzles** & Code Golf*. Or maybe just *Programming Puzzles*.

<sup>See other answers for about dropping the "*& Code Golf*" or not.</sup>

Answer (score -13):

<sup>*Upvote this if you agree and downvote if you disagree.*</sup>

Yes, we should rename this site to *Programming **Tournaments** & Code Golf*. Or maybe just *Programming Tournaments*.

<sup>See other answers for about dropping the "*& Code Golf*" or not.</sup>

Comment: Tournaments makes no sense. We don't have brackets, except this kind: []