# What's the point of a puzzle tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why is there a [puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) tag? Surely every problem posted on this site is puzzle meaning that it could be applied to everything..

The same applies to the [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The puzzle tag is [on the way out](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1588/194).

The programming puzzle tag has quite a narrow scope. Read its tag wiki.