# Free privileges with "Graduation Userscript"

Tags: support, voting

I just noticed something about my account. I just recently discovered the [Graduation Userscript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/graduation-design-ideas/7955#7955). I then noticed that I was (not actually) close to getting the privilege "See Vote Counts". I tried it on a question, and guess what? [image: Null]I turn the stylesheet off? [image: None] I don't want to lose this privilege, but what is happening? Is it something with the userscript? You can see from the screenshots that I have 538 repuation the whole time. I can't read JavaScript Userscripts so I couldn't tell if I looked at the userscript. The same thing happens on my other laptop.

Comment: The API exposes the up and down count as API responses aren't associated with a privilege level for most cases. [It's pretty easy to write](https://github.com/The-Quill/VoteCountViewer/blob/master/vote-count-viewer.user.js) anyway.

Comment: It's user***script*** by the way, not user*sheet* :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vote breakdowns are trivially exposed to userscripts (you can even get them from Stack Exchange Data Explorer) but without such a script you're limited by privilege reputation thresholds. You don't have enough reputation to see vote breakdowns but anyone can see vote breakdowns with Downgoat's userscript.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Should I delete the question because it is answered, or keep it? I'm new to Meta...

Comment: @NoOneIsHere I see no reason to delete the question. You can accept the answer just as one would on the other Q&A sites.