# Change code font to DejaVu

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

The current stylesheet specifies the code font as `Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif`.

Unfortunately, the first fonts are not very good for programming languages with non-ASCII symbols, e.g. the not-identical symbol `≢` [renders wrong on Chrome for Windows](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=620629).

DejaVu Sans Mono supports a wide swath of Unicode, and is indeed [the font used on TIO](https://tio.run/nexus).

We should specify that font first.

Comment: DejaVu Sans Mono is also the font I use for viewing/coding in ESMin, but I definitely think that this is a really good idea for rendering other languages like Funciton too.

Comment: `≢` also renders wrongly on Chrome for macOS

Comment: @Cowsquack My issue was wrongly closed as WontFix. Can you maybe post a similar issue regarding macOS with screenshots etc.?