# Do we need leaderboards on all challenges?

Tags: discussion

I noticed a bunch of edits showing up in the edits queue where the usual javascript leaderboard is added to challenges.

[Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76379/a-simple-tcp-server)
[Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110974/blink-the-caps-lock)

I think the leaderboards are fine, but do we really need to add these to challenges that have been inactive for quite some while?

Comment: We definitely don't need them on [tag:code-golf] challenges as the userscript includes a leaderboard for them.

Comment: The userscript?

Comment: @shaggy Not everyone uses the userscript.

Comment: See [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7955/58974), @JarkoDubbeldam

Comment: @Shaggy Not everyone uses that.

Comment: Really? I would have thought most did.

Comment: ...Would I upvote to agree with your implication that we _don't_ need leaderboards on inactive questions, or would I downvote to disagree with the title?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Voting on answers with a stance is the way to go :)

Comment: @Shaggy Nope. I doubt that many people know it exists since it's quite hard to find. I don't use it because I can't run it on Chrome AFAIK

Comment: @BetaDecay I have it running on chrome.

Comment: @Shaggy I don't use userscripts or the graduation design script or whatever. I use vanilla SE. Although, if the new SE design gets moved to PPCG like SO has, I might consider it. I hate the new SO look.

Comment: @mbomb007 With you on the last point.

Answer (score 19):

## Not *all* challenges require leaderboards

The reason leaderboards are used at all is to find answers based on byte count, based on language, based on user, etc.. Finding answers is not a big problem on challenges that only have a page's worth of answers or less.

However, challenges with over 30 answers can get clunky to search for answers in. In that case, when the challenge was posted does not matter as either way, a leaderboard is useful.

Now, I am not saying we need to put a leaderboard on every challenge stat. If you're going to edit leaderboards in, be considerate of how you're going to be bumping it to the home page. Don't bump dozens of old challenges just for this purpose. A good way of going about this is putting a leaderboard on a challenge if you are about to answer it, in which case it will be useful to you and others as they come in later.

The "popularity" of a challenge is also a factor. Note that this is slightly subjective. Before you stick a leaderboard on a challenge, think about whether the challenge is something that will be searched often.

There's a possibility that every challenger could include a leaderboard. While I do not currently see any disadvantages to this, I'm not sure if the community would agree.

Comment: I'll just upvote this :)

Comment: I think the activity on a challenge is quite relevant. On one of the linked challenges the last activity was Nov 21 2016, if we don't count the edit made for the leaderboard. While I agree with this answer, I don't think we should necro challenges left and right.

Comment: Just because a challenge hasn't had a lot of answers recently, does not mean nobody is looking to answer it and checking if their solution has already been taken. :) Remember, answering an old challenge is completely fine.

Comment: True, but is that small chance worth the clutter on the homepage?

Comment: I have addressed this in the answer.

Comment: I think that a leaderboard can be useful for challenges with only one page of answers; I still find it beats scanning or searching for a certain language.

Comment: To some extent, I agree that every post could use a leaderboard. However, unless SE gives that to us built-in, it's not gonna be easy to execute.