# Footer text is hard to read on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, css

The styling of the footer on codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com is very low contrast and the text is hard to read, especially the list subtitles. I have selected some of the text "NETWORK", which helps, but this still needs to be fixed.

Here is a screenshot - or just scroll down a bit ;)

[image: hard to read footer]

I'm using Firefox 88.0b3 on Linux.

Comment: Can replicate, on Chrome 89.0 on Windows

Comment: Not a proper answer, but this isn't an issue for those using the [gradscript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7955/31716). If you are using it and wish to see for yourself, you'll have to turn it off

Comment: Thanks for the alert! I can see the issue here, too. We'll be addressing this as part of our bug duty!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: this appears to no longer be an issue; the footer is now readable. If any other issues appear with the footer, please raise it as a separate [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)-report.

---

I can confirm, this is an issue for me as well. I will forward this to whatever channels I can to get it fixed as soon as possible (and I've added [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) so hopefully this will be reviewed soon), but until it is fixed, I made a quick userscript that just sets the text color to `0xCCCCCC` (it's a hacky solution but the worst it could end up doing is just set too many things to that text color).

https://gist.github.com/hyper-neutrino/189e3bc21d3b1eafacabe6c0874533bc