# Change the stackexhange subdomain to "ppcg.stackexchange.com" and let the original redirect

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

A large amount (20-60%) of the questions here are not code golf questions. It might also confuse new users.

Comment: I think it is fine as is, and that would require all-holy Dev Intervention™/

Comment: @EasterlyIrk A mod should post this to meta SE. If only SE was open-source... it would be a pull request away...

Comment: Requests that are specific to PPCG would get migrated here anyway.

Comment: Additionally, about 25% of all questions are *not* tagged with [tag:code-golf], and that percentage would likely be lower if we only looked at the last year or so. A large number, yes, but there are three [tag:code-golf] questions for every non-code-golf question. `codegolf.stackexchange.com` makes sense, it's primarily what we do.

Comment: My favourite type of challenge here is non-code-golf, but I oppose this change. ppcg would mean even less to newcomers than codegolf. Also, attracting golfers is a good thing. They write some of the most interesting non-golf solutions too.

Answer (score 20):

### Let's keep it as is

We've been Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, otherwise known as CodeGolf.SE, since our inception 5 years ago. Our name [doesn't suit us perfectly](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5759/20469), but it's part of our identity. And now that we're [graduating](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8538/20469), we should avoid changing our identity and embrace what we've accomplished as CodeGolf.SE.

That aside, the subdomain name "code golf," despite being only a subset of what we do here, is [descriptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf). "PPCG" is meaningless without context. Indeed, the rest of the Stack Exchange network knows us as Code Golf; few people know what "PPCG" is.

So let's stay us.

Answer (score -2):

## Let both coexist

When you go to codegolf.se, it keeps that URL (clicking around gets you to the same domain), but let the same be for ppcg.se.

Comment: I don't think the SE software is designed to allow this.

Comment: @AlexA. To the extent that the site always redirects you to the canonical host name regardless of which site alias you visit, this is by design: you want search engines to have results in the canonical place.