# 404 Not Found image is itself 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-page

It looks like the image that is supposed to show up in the [404 error page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/404) has...itself gone 404, and shows a broken image.

It looks like it's trying to load the image from https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/img/404.png, but that link is 404 (as of right now).

Per MEE's comment, it looks like the [500 server error page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/error) and the [captcha page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/captcha) are also serving 404 images.

Can this please be fixed? (Also, can someone please create the [404-not-found](/questions/tagged/404-not-found) tag on this site, as it doesn't exist, and there don't seem to be any relevant tags other than the required tag to use?)

**Update:** It seems that the broken image was manually resolved by changing the URL of the loaded image to the same one used on beta and non-designed sites, i.e. https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/beta/img/404.png. However, the site-specific 404 image, linked above, is still broken. Is this site not going to get a uniquely-designed 404 error page as part of its design?

Comment: Also here: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17767/71966

Comment: The 404 tag does exist, it's just that nobody can find it. (Just for clarification, it doesn't _actually_ exist, I was just kidding :P)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Mind creating it, since you have the rep?

Comment: @gparyani I'm not sure; it's fine for a question to have one required tag and nothing else if it simply is more specific and isn't generally categorized as something like "how does this rule work under this specific situation". I don't think this tag would be too applicable because of the 5 meta questions containing 404, three of them (including this) ask why the 404 image is a 404 (pretty common bug I guess???).

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Over on Meta Stack Exchange, those three questions would fit under the tag, as the tag also represents the *page*, not just the error. Also, according to an SE community manager, "[*if a question doesn't have any tags other than the required tag, it's untagged...we don't prevent this, but maybe we should*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320535/377214)"

Comment: @gparyani Hm alright

Comment: I'm going to mark this as [meta-tag:status-completed], since the 404 issue is fixed and it is now loading correctly. If we want a customized 404, that should probably be opened as a new meta proposal so it can be reviewed by the team.