# Typo in Site Header Banner!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, status-deferred, site-design

An extra W here. Better get someone fixing it XD

[image: Typo in CGCC Header Banner]

Comment: That might be a C++ variant where W is the escape character which needs another W to escape it

Comment: @mousetail Given that the full snippet is just `main(){puts("Hello, WWorld!");}}`, I'd think it's just regular C.

Comment: I agree with Bbrk24. In addition, how is anyone supposed to know that it's some obscure variant? By Occam's razor we should just see it as regular C.

Comment: Obscure variants of languages is like this sites entire point

Comment: @mousetail They should at least go with more identifiable ones. The ArnoldC in the previous line, for instance, is pretty good. `IT'S SHOWTIME TALK TO THE HAND` immediately tells you what it is.

Answer (score 3):

#### This almost certainly won't get changed

To start with, I'd argue that it isn't even a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in the first place, but I think that's beside the point to be honest.

[SE designed our banner](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17760/66833) to

> be more representative of Code Golfing

The exact design was done by them, not by any of us, as far as I can tell. As such, what is and isn't an intended part of the design is, more or less, unknowable to us. It certainly appears to be a bunch of different programs that output `Hello, World!`, but whether any of them are incorrect or not, only SE and the original designer can say. Therefore, especially given that it's incredibly minor and we've gone 4 years without anyone raising it as an issue before, I *really* doubt it'll get changed.

Therefore, at least for the moment, I'm tagging this as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). If a designer at SE has a free moment and wants to fix this, however, they're more than welcome to.

Comment: Sounds like a good point. Anyway, can you guys at least bump the votes back to 0 so that this post still possibly gets looked at by the designers? If I were one I certainly wouldn't be wasting my time on something with negative votes ...

Comment: @ShiranYuan The devs do a semi-regular check in for all [bug] reports on sites, and I've added the [status-deferred] tag as well. The question's score is (mostly) irrelevant, except for guaging site interest in fixing the bug, which doesn't matter for something this small

Comment: Got it, thanks!