# What should this site be called now that it has a name?

Tags: discussion, site-name

[This post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17612/43319) says:

> [This site is now "Code Golf & Coding Challenges"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/heres-your-site-design-preview)

Indeed, this is what it says in our banner too:

> ## CODE GOLF
>
> & coding challenges

But our tour page says:

> ## Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange
>
> **Code Golf Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site (…)

And on Meta, the <kbd>**?**</kbd> menu has:

> **Back to Code Golf Stack Exchange**
>   Return to the main site

#### How should we call this site, both on the site itself, and when mentioning it to the outside world, e.g. [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Esolang:Community_portal) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)?

Comment: The official name is "Code Golf", despite the subtitle. The subtitle is just a part of the header logo.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer That's not what @Catija♦ wrote.

Comment: I meant that "Code Golf" is how the site is named in the system.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I didn't ask how it is named in the system, but rather how it should be *called*.

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve here? Code Golf isn't going to be mad based on using the subtitle or not. I call my dad "Mr. Man" and he seems to be fine with that. Disclaimer: My last name is not "Man".

Answer (score 26):

## Code Golf

We voted to [name our site Code Golf and keep a subtitle *in the logo*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17615/12012), mostly for clarification purposes. This is what we should do.

The main drawback of referring to the site as *Code Golf & Coding Challenges* is clear: nobody is *ever* going to spell it out, so we're once more left with an obscure acronym that is meaningless for outsiders. This was also my first point when [I proposed to name the site Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17613/12012).

Answer (score 6):

> The new site name is "Code Golf", and the subtitle is "& coding challenges". You can refer to the site with or without the subtitle – [*trichoplax 19 mins ago*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#comment63765_17845)
>
> (referring to it off site should probably include "Stack Exchange" as other golfing sites are available) – [*trichoplax 14 mins ago*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#comment63766_17845)